# vim-latexsuite syntax highlight in macro parameter

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex

I'm using vim with [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) to edit my LaTeX-files. I noticed that the `\begin{env}` and `\end{env}` are not colorized when they are in a macro parameter (the `\vary` command and `question` environment are part of the [exsheets package](http://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets)):

```
\vary{
  \begin{question}
  \end{question}
}{
  \begin{question}
  \end{question}
}
```

I've attached a sample picture:
[image: explanation of my problem]

What should I do to colorize the `\begin{question}` inside `\vary`?

PS. I've asked it on [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306042/vim-latexsuite-syntax-highlight-in-macro-parameter) but no answer.